# Can I use multiMap to consume two items in a stream

Tags: java

I want to implement a function such like:

```
Stream<Long> stream;
stream.forEach(id->{
    Object obj = loadObj(id);
    doSomething(id, obj);
});
```

Can I implement it using method references such as when `doSomething` only requires one parameter

```
Stream<Long> stream;
stream.map(this::loadObj).forEach(this::doSomething)
```

Comment: Of course I have searched and tried some possible ways. The question I asked involves more knowledge rather than work effort. If there really is a solution and someone happen to know, I think it would not take much effort to post it, after all, the answer has one line code only and the question needs several lines to ask. I don't know why would you connect my question with beer.

Comment: @matt Thanks, I just take id as an example, not real scenario. I think I was just misled by the name of function ```Stream.mapMulti()``` and to believe it is possible to map multi values parallel.

Comment: I've changed your question quite a bit, but I think it is a good question because multiMap is new and a quick search didnt' come up with something. I suspect people will try similar.

Answer (score 1):

[multiMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) is designed to map single items to multiple outputs. So you have one Item in and you'll get 0 or more Objects out in the next stream.

The second argument is provided by the implementation of mapMulti. Each time consume is used, the output stream will have another object.

Stream#mapMulti is also an **intermediate operation**, so it isn't a suitable replacement for forEach. The best is to stick with what you have, or a bit more concisely:

```
stream.forEach( id -> doSomething( id, loadObj( id ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the answer in your question. Assuming loadObj and doSomething are both methods of `this`.

```
stream.map(this::loadObj).forEach(this::doSomething)
```

Comment: It seems you misunderstand my question. I mean what if ```doSomething``` need to take two parameters, and that's to say ```map``` need to produce two results. I mean how to map that.

Comment: Oh, you can not use method references for that. If you really want to use them make a class that wraps the two values.